# converting .ovpn file to these 3 files: ca.crt, client.crt, client.key

Tags: vpn, openvpn

[vpnbook.com](http://www.vpnbook.com/freevpn) offers a free openVPN service. This is one of their files: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7231382/ with the name `vpnbook-uk1-tcp80.ovpn`.

I want to convert it to 3 files to be usable in network-manager-openvpn:

[image]

Comment: i have tried a lot of things but at last this worked for me https://naveensnayak.wordpress.com/2013/03/04/ubuntu-openvpn-with-ovpn-file/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a script [here](https://github.com/ryanniehaus/useful_scripts/blob/master/openvpn_conversion_for_network-manager/update_vpnprovidersinfo_and_extract_certs.sh) to automate fetching password & zip files from vpn websites such as [vpnbook.com](http://vpnbook.com), extracting the `ca`, `cert`, and `key` data from the ovpn files, and updating the opvn files so the certs should just import for you.

Answer (score 4):

Copy the text between `<ca>` and `</ca>`, paste it in a text editor and save it as `ca.crt`. The text between `<cert>` and `</cert>` should be saved as `client.crt` and the text between `<key>` and `</key>` should be saved as `client.key`.

---

You must set some advanced options in accordance to the configuration file. I couldn't connect to servers using port 80, but port 443 works for me. This is what I did:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Password with Cert would be my guess.

Comment: @onrea answer updated.

Comment: @Eric, Thanks, Worked charming, However, it's odd why network manager does not support `.ovpn` files!

Answer (score 0):

since all ovpn files are all simple plain text files, you can create a python scripts with the following logic:

(1) read the contents of ovpn text file;

(2) grab relevant text between tags using regular expression;

```
def grabBetweenTag(tagName, fileContents):

    betweentag = re.findall('<'+tagName+'>.*\n(^.*$.*\n[\S\n]+.*$\n)</'+tagName+'>', fileContents, re.MULTILINE)

    return betweentag[0]

grabBetweenTag('ca', fileContents)
grabBetweenTag('cert', fileContents)
grabBetweenTag('key', fileContents)
```

(3) copy that text into a new text file;

(4) the mapping between tags and new-text-file to create looks like this:

- All text between '<ca>' and '</ca>'will be used to create '**ca.crt';
- All text between '<cert>' and '</cert>' will be used to create '**client.crt';
- All text between '<key>' and '</key>' will be used to create '**client.key'.

I created this [repository](https://github.com/jansenicus/ovpn-to-certificates) as an example implementation of that logic to grab all  ovpn files and create certificates

## *.ovpn --> *-ca.crt, *-client.crt, *-client.key

Answer (score 0):

In Gnome you can just click the + to add VPN:

[image: Plus]

And then select OpenVPN here:

[image: OpenVPN]

Then you can open the `.ovpn` file.

Unfortunately it doesn't provide a way to load a new `.opvn` into an existing VPN config, so the easiest way if you want to change an existing VPN is to delete it and make a new one.